# Not able to redirect after logging in

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, authorization

I am working on an application in which after logging in we are redirected to the protected route but I am facing an issue, when I enter username and password and hit login it is successfully calling the API and setting the token in `localstorage` but it is not redirecting to the protected route but when I enter credentials again then it is working fine.
Here is the code where I guess is having problem:

```
const submitAction = (data) => {
    dispatch(login(data));
    history.push(`${private_component}`);
};
```

data is basically username and password and I am using Redux that's why dispatching the login action where I am calling API and storing tokens in `localstorage` and user-related data in redux.
I guess the `history.push` is being called before the tokens get stored in `localstorage`. Can anyone suggest me solution?

Comment: What is `private_component`?

Answer (score 1):

You may want the `login` action to return a Promise, so you can wait until the API call is finished.  What's probably happening is that you're pushing to the protected route before the line above has finished, so the user isn't actually logged in. That would also explain why it works the second time around.  Another possibility would be to move the redirect into the login action itself, as long as it's handled after the response is received and the user is logged in.

```
export function login = (username, password) => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // your code
    fetch('wherever', {whatever: 'config'} ).then(r => r.json()).then(d => resolve(d)).catch(e => reject(e))
  }
)
```

something like that may allow you to then do

```
const submitAction = (data) => {
  dispatch(login(data))
    .then(history.push(`${private_component}`));
}
```

this is really just psuedocode, so forgive any mistakes that may not work exactly, but hopefully it gets the idea across.